# QBF in APTIME - Why APTIME and not ALOGSPACE?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I have a brief proof about QBF being $\in$ APTIME, which claims that you can use the additional input of the alternation as values for your QBF formula.

And therefore you can accept, if the quantifier less formula $\psi$ is true, given the additional input.

That makes sense, but if you assume $\psi$ in 3-CNF. I could make that check in SPACE$(\log n)$ and therefore, I could solve QBF in $\mathbf{ALOGSPACE}$, which would place QBF in $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{ALOGSPACE}$, that obviously can't be true, but I don't see my mistake.

The proof claims runtime: $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$

I know that APTIME = PSPACE and QBF is PSPACE complete therefore QBF is APTIME complete, so what am I missing?

Comment: Of course quantifierless formula also is in APTIME. Or when you say PTIME, do you mean that it is DTIME?

Comment: I just realized some major confusion regarding TIME and SPACE here, therefore I edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the "additional input of the alterations"? Alternating machine is a non deterministic machine with quantifier-labeled states and a different definition of acceptance, what exactly do you mean by "additional input"? Also, what check are you saying you can perform in logspace, this is not clear from your formulation.

Comment: Well, checking a certificate for SAT is in ALOGSPACE = P. But it is unknown if solving it is in ALOGSPACE.

Comment: You need to remember your choices for the quantified variables, which you can't do in logspace.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks! That was my mistake! To the others: My definition of the TM was like that: You have 3 tapes, first tape "normal input" second tape "additional input", where the TM may only go right and not left and of course the work tape.